# Salt in cryptography

Tags: encryption, salt

I was reading about salts in hashing and cryptography and I saw that in other answers in StackOverflow about salting:

salting is adding data to the password (or anything we want to encrypt) to make it harder for people who want to crack it with bruteforce and rainbow tables.

for example, my password is PASSWORD and my salt is SALT so the program converts it to `PASSWORDSALT` and then hash it.

But it does not work when I used `scrypt` and `blake` (I have not tried other encryption types with salt)

Python code:

```
>>> blake2b(b'PASSWORD', salt=b'SALT').hexdigest()
52d9cb2e8690fcc5d34ef948e09c51aae66ff1d8e099bb72e2db333d6aa90b12c1745872b72004d6a64210cbb9be11307817f156863073d85cad0f2d643a4416
>>> blake2b(b'PASSWORDSALT').hexdigest()
aa2fd2094ec83915eef264d4f24870f3d2ebb676449bc824161cf53aa62142dd64e5a80214a0638195eb1d3c2474727711c4e2149d10afc5767c0c25f5625a54
```

So Why they are not equal?

Comment: `blake2b` pads the salt with zeroes to a constant length (16 bytes, I think). I don't have a working instantiation of `blake2b` to play with, so I don't know whether that's sufficient to solve the mystery.

Comment: A salt that doesn't change is useless. Ideally the salt should be unpredictable, but it should at least be different for each password.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Hi James, why would it ideally be unpredictable? For even better protection against rainbow tables? Generally you'd use a large random salt (~128 bits) so you don't have to keep track of a counter at the very least.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: A 128-bit random salt is perfect. I was thinking of one particular scenario which is so far-fetched it's not worth considering. Rainbow tables are normally only useful for recovering multiple passwords as the work to build them is more expensive than brute-forcing a single password drawn from the same space. However, if the attacker has one very high-value target in mind he might be willing to build the table in advance of the attacker using the predicted salt so that when the account is finally created they can recover the password more quickly. Far-fetched as I said.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Well, unless some kind of application identifier is used, it would be possible to create a rainbow table to attack multiple organizations with the same set of tables, so it's not **that** far fetched. Maybe only attack the first 10, possibly one of them is for an account with elevated privileges. So in the end just using 128 random bits is probably for the best.

Answer (score 2):

The password and salt are just inputs to a password hash function. Password hash functions are allowed to have more than one input. This is different from a secure hash such as SHA-256 that simply takes a single input to hash: the message.

If you look at the [Blake specification](https://blake2.net/blake2.pdf#page=6) you will see in section 2.8 that the salt is put in a parameter block, and that it is *not* used as separate input for each iteration.

Comment: It's probably best to read the specifications instead of guessing the actual mechanisms inside the password hash. The papers are generally pretty readable.